# Programmatically set value on bootstrap dropdown menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap dropdown menu with two options:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="button-methods" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width: 100%;">"Pick Up Method To Create a Layer" 
     <span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-methods" style="width: 95%;">
        <li><a href="#" id="excel_layer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>"Create a layer"</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="empty_layer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>"Create an empty layer"</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to programmatically set the second option of the dropdown menu when the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JQuery selector to select the second LI DOM object under the appropriate parent as you wish and set it in the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Set value for your Dropdown
    $('div ul li').eq(1).find('span').eq(1).text('what ever you need');

    // Direct Selector to the object is also as (Maybe better than the above one I gave you before):
    $('#empty_layer').text('what ever you need');
}
```

Comment: Something like: $('div ul li').eq(1).find('span').eq(1).text('what ever you need');

Comment: Thanks. What is 'span'?

Comment: span is an HTML tag as you can see in your HTML Markup.
Please accept my answer if you liked it, thanks.